# NDVI processing template does not scale from -1 to 1 on WorldView-2 Mosaic Dataset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, mosaic-dataset, raster-functions

I am trying to apply the NDVI raster function to a mosaic dataset with WorldView-2 tiles. When I use the NDVI raster function and "Create new layer", the values displayed range between -1 and 1 as I would expect and are displayed with a colormap. The only problem is that instead of having a separate layer, I want a user to be able to see NDVI visualized as a raster function (i.e. Mosaic Layer > Data > Processing Templates). To do so, I try to apply the NDVI raster function to my Mosaic Dataset first by clicking "Save As" instead of "Create new layer" in the NDVI raster function, and then by applying it to my mosaic dataset (via Manage Processing Templates). The result is grayscale and has a value range between 3.4e+38 and -3.4e+38. I see this value range in this Esri video as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UlVlN0G9qk&t=1402s at 20:00 and do not understand the value range. Furthermore, when I change the color scheme (grayscale to colormap) to compare them, they do not match. Also, when I save the Raster Function from the output layer of Create New Layer (the one that created a value range of -1 to 1), and then apply it to the mosaic dataset, I do not get the same -1 to 1 range or colormap-- I get the grayscale and 3.4e+38 and -3.4e+38 value range output. I do not understand why saving the raster function that worked and then applying it to the same dataset gives a different output.

How can I get processing template applied to my mosaic dataset with the expected range of -1 to 1 and with a typical NDVI colormap?

Raster Function that gives different results whether "Create new layer" or "Save As" is selected.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure 3.4e+38 and -3.4e+38 is the real output range?  Are worldview image in DN or reflectance? Did you check scene values with info tool? There are a lot of things to clarify, or at least share the output. I think you need to compute statistics to that image and the range you see is the typical float image range.

Comment: Thanks, I do calculate statistics with Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset and the imagery is Standard 2A, so it should be radiance instead of DN.